# Selecting records from PostgreSQL after the primary key has cycled?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL 9.5 table that is set to cycle when the primary key ID hits the maximum value. For argument's sake, lets the maximum ID value can be 999,999. I'll add commas to make the numbers easier to read.

We run a job that deletes data from the table that is older than 45 days. Let's assume that the table now only contains records with IDs of 999,998 and 999,999.

The primary key ID cycles back to 1 and 20 more records have been written. I need to keep it generic so I won't make any assumptions about how many were written. In my real world needs, I don't care how many were written.

How can I select the records without getting duplicates with an ID of 999,998 and 999,999?

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE ID >0;

Would return (in no particular order):

999,998
999,999
1
2
...
20
```

My real world case is that I need to publish every record that was written to the table to a message broker. I maintain a separate table that tracks the row ID and timestamp of the last record that was published. The pseudo-query/pseudo-algorithm to determine what new records to write is something like this. The IF statement handles when the primary key ID cycles back to 1 as I need to read the new record written after the ID cycled:

```
SELECT * from my_table WHERE id > last_written_id
PUBLISH each record
if ID of last record published == MAX_TABLE_ID (e.g 999,999):
    ??? What to do here? I need to get the newest records where ID >= 1 but less than the oldest record I have
```

I realise that the "code" is rough, but it's really just an idea at the moment so there's no code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, you can use the current value of the sequence to do what you want:

```
select t.*
from my_table t
where t.id > @last_written_id or
      (currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('my_table', 'id')) < @last_written_id and
       t.id <= currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('my_table', 'id')) 
      );
```

This is not a 100% solution.  After all, 2,000,000 records could have been added so the numbers will all be repeated or the records deleted.  Also, if you have inserts happening while the query is running -- particularly in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: Thanks - let me digest this for a while. SQL isn't my strong point.

Comment: One process writes to the table while another process reads the records and publishes them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a completely different approach: You could completely fill the table, giving it a column for deletion time. So instead of deleting rows, you merely set this datetime. And instead of inserting a row you merely update the one that was deleted the longest time ago:

```
update my_table
set col1 = 123, col2 = 456, col3 = 'abc', deletion_datetime = null
where deletion_datetime = 
(
  select deletion_datetime
  from my_table
  where deletion_datetime is not null
  order by deletion_datetime
  limit 1
);
```